# Export table into multiple files using DTS, setup wizard doesn't remember past entries

Tags: sql-server, dts

I have a table that needs to be split up into say 30 files.

The table already has the FileNumber column so it is easy to know which rows should be exported to while file.

```
Users
-UserID
-FileNumber
-...
```

So to get file#1 i would select:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE FileNumber=1
```

For file#2

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE FileNumber=2
```

The problem is that the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard doesn't allow me to run it multiple times with the same settings.  I have to go through the entire wizard, enter my credentials, query etc. for each file.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: I would go with SSIS and a loop container.

Comment: Check [this post](https://coldlogics.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/using-ssis-to-dynamically-create-data-files-from-a-full-result-set/), it is very similar for your case.

Comment: Can't you save the DTS package as an external file?